# Add a Store Procedure from c# code in visual Fox Pro database using odbc or vfoledb

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, visual-foxpro

I have a Visual Fox Pro database in which i need to add a stored procedure if its not already there. I can add stored procedure using VFP but i want to do it without user interaction.

```
try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=YES;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;SourceDB=" + dbpath + "/sample.dbc"))
            {


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

above is my code to open database. And below is sample stored procedure

```
Function GetMax( tcTableName, tcFieldName )
Local Array laMax[1]
Select Max( &tcFieldName ) ;
    from (m.tcTableName) ;
    into Array laMax
Return laMax[1]
Endfunc
```

Comment: You are using ODBC which is not valid for a VFP database after version 6, use OLEDB instead. Other than that check the sample I gave, it would work that way (I wouldn't create an SP for that sample code but if you wish).

Comment: Thank you very much, i was not sure that it was possible using ODBC or not. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you should do that using VFP. You may try with ExecScript but I doubt that it would work (I haven't tried).

EDIT: I tried this out of curiosity and to my surprise it worked:

```
static void Main()
{
string myCode = 
@"procedure SPTest(tcTableName)
select * from (m.tcTableName) into cursor crsTest nofilter
setresultset('crsTest')
endproc";

File.WriteAllText(@"d:\temp\TestSP.prg",myCode);

  string strCon = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=d:\temp";
  using(  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
  {
    con.Open();    
    var xs = new OleDbCommand("TestSP", con);
    xs.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    xs.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"update ('d:\temp\TestSP.dbc') 
      set Code = ? where ObjectName='StoredProceduresSource'", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("spCode", myCode);  
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"update ('d:\temp\TestSP.dbc') 
      set Code = ? where ObjectName='StoredProceduresObject'", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("spCode", File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\temp\TestSP.fxp"));  
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
   } 

   DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
   using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=d:\temp\TestSP.dbc"))
   {
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand("spTest");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("spCode", @"d:\temp\MyCustomers");  
    con.Open();
    tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    con.Close();
   }
   // LinqPad
   // tbl.Dump();
}
```